# OpenCV resize issue(resize.cpp:4045: error:) in Android

Tags: opencv, android

I was creating Android application with OpenCV 3.4 but the screen size(expected full Screen) is not working out for me so I made some changes in OpenCV library in CameraBridgeViewBase.java and JavaCameraView.

And I found that there is error in resizing the frame.

```
resize.cpp:4045: error: (-215) dsize.area() > 0
```

Please find the changes which I have done in CameraBridgeViewBase.java at line 465

```
protected void AllocateCache()
{
    mCacheBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getHeight(), getWidth(), 
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

and in JavaCameraView.java at line 179

```
mFrameWidth = getHeight();//params.getPreviewSize().width;
mFrameHeight = getWidth(); //params.getPreviewSize().height;
```

I have found that somewhat same problem in other languages too for resizing.

Please help me with this.

This is the actual error I am getting.

```
E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dsize.area() > 0 || (inv_scale_x > 0 && inv_scale_y > 0)) in void cv::resize(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::Size, double, double, int), file /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp, line 4045

E/org.opencv.imgproc: imgproc::resize_11() caught cv::Exception: /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:4045: error: (-215) dsize.area() > 0 || (inv_scale_x > 0 && inv_scale_y > 0) in function void cv::resize(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::Size, double, double, int)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason triggering the exception of resize function usually divided zero. You can check the values of getHeight() and getWidth()